# Solve the system for the given parameter a

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

\begin{align}
ax+y+z&=1,\\
2x+2ay+2z&=3\\
x+y+az&=1
\end{align}

I tried forming the system matrix and discuss it using its rank, but I'm not sure how to row reduce:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&1&1&1\\ 2&2a&2&3\\ 1&1&a&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: A few questions about *very similar* system:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843749/solutions-of-a-system-of-linear-equations-with-a-parameter
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930252/system-of-linear-equations-how-many-solutions
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213108/using-determinants-to-find-a-unique-solution

Answer (score 2):

Consider the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a&1&1\\2&2a&2\\1&1&a
\end{pmatrix}.$$ We have that $\det(A)=2(a-1)^2(a+2)$. Hence if $a\neq 1$ and $a\neq -2$, then $A$ is invertible and the solution of the system of equations is $A^{-1}b$, where $b=\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\1
\end{pmatrix}$.

If $a=1$, then the system of equations is false, hence there are no solutions. If $a=-2$, then again the system of equations has no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If yo have a linear system $A x = b$, where $A$ is a matrix and $x$ and $b$ are vectors, the solution is given by $x = A^{-1} b$, provided $A$ is invertible. So the right hand side of the equation should not be included in the system matrix $A$ (like you did).

Comment: This is not correct. If $A$ is invertible then this system has the unique solution $A^{-1}b$, but if $A$ is not invertible, the system is either false or has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Right, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your systems of equations and I hope that this is acceptable because I didn't use matrix. Obviously, I haven't learned that yet. Here it is: 
$$
\begin{aligned}
ax + y + z = 1 && (\mathrm{Eq}_1)\\
2x + 2ay + 2z = 3 && (\mathrm{Eq}_2)\\
x+y+az=1 && (\mathrm{Eq}_3)
\end{aligned}
$$
Now
$$
(\mathrm{Eq}_1) - (\mathrm{Eq}_1) = (a-1)(x-z) = 0\Longrightarrow\begin{cases}
a=1 & \text{no solution}\\
x=z
\end{cases}
$$
with $x=z$ we have
\begin{aligned}
(a+1)x + y = 1 && (\mathrm{Eq}_1)\\
2x + ay = 1.5 && (\mathrm{Eq}_2)
\end{aligned}
I replaced the value of $y$ in $(\mathrm{Eq}_1)$ with the value of $y$ in $(\mathrm{Eq}_2)$. After that, I solved it as usual.